# Search and display certain table element

Tags: c#, database, search, visual-studio-2012, local

I'm trying to search my local database table and simply display all it's columns.

I start my sending in

```
SearchID("1234");
```

My code so far:

```
 private static void SearchID(string CostumerID)
 {
     string conStr = @"Data Source = C:\Users\secwp_000\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Module5\Module5\Orderdatabase.sdf";
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conStr);
     SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM [Order]", con);

     SqlCeDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

     SqlCeDataAdapter adapt = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
     adapt.Fill(ds, "Order");

     while (dr.Read()) 
     {
         string str = (string)dr[1];
         if (str == CostumerID)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(str);
         }
     }
 }
```

Where am I thinking wrong?

It stops on

```
SqlCeDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

saying i don't have a connection. But just sounds wierd, because I've just had connection..

Comment: add this line con.Open() after sqlCedDataAdapater, let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to open connection using

```
If(con.state.toString()=="closed")
con.open();
```

I observe a fault in your query why are you compare your result after fetch from database.you can directly filter in SQL query

```
Select * from order where table.customer_Id = customerId
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a connection but you haven't opened it yet:

```
con.Open();
adapt.Fill(ds, "Order");
con.Close();
```

In addition you should use `using` statements for disposable objects like `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` to make sure they will be disposed properly:

```
using(SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conStr))
using(SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM [Order]", con))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel so stupid for not seeing this, haha. And it worked! But it wont display anything from the table,
    while (dr.Read()) 
            {
                string str = (string)dr[1];
                if (str == CostumerID)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(str);
                }
            }

Following instructions given to me, there is nothing wrong with this code, and it could display Order with costumerID 1234.